# Save multiple sheets in a new workbook in a particular file format

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to read up a few related posts on the forum but wasnt able to make a code work or understand the syntax of a few functions.

I will try to describe what I want to be done in a crisp fashion:

- I have a workbook with the multiple sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2 ... Sheet 5) and I want to create a macro assigned button to **Save as a new work book** containing only Sheet 1, Sheet 2 and Sheet3
- The file format should be Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls)
- On clicking the Macro assigned button the Save as dialogue box should pop up allowing the user to select destination and also optionally a new file name (pre assigned file name can be "textstring123"
- After the workbook is saved the workbook should open for user to inspect while the old workbook is minimised

I am using Excel 2013, in case that is relevant.

The post may seem crude but I have no choice but to seek help from you as I have been breaking my head over this for the last day and a half and without this the rest of my macro project will become a waste. Thank you in advance for and suggestion/advice/ help.

If any other details or clarification is required please do ask.

I have added my lines of code that I have made but doesnt seem to work properly.

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
' Save as
''
Dim varResult As Variant
Sheets(Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3")).Copy
varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
             "Excel Files *.xls", FileFormat:=-57, Title:="Save File", _
            InitialFileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path \ Textstring123.xls)
If varResult <> False Then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=varResult, _
FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal

     Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

[image: Highlighted in yellow is the line where debugger gives runtime error]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Post your code even if it is not working, that way it doesn't seem that you are just ordering some code and show that you tried! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have added the code. The last thing I want is to make someone code for me, I just want to explore and learn but atm I am blind and need some valuable guidance.

Comment: @R3uK I have attached a screenshot of the debugger, Im not able to figure out the problem

Comment: Very strange, I'd have understood if it was on the next row but that the error is on `For Each`... Leaves me speechless... Nope the variable is declared and that should be enough... It is working on my computers so I don't get how it doesn't work for you... Maybe try asking another question on this specific issue, because an `Out of Range` on a `For Each` it's really the 1st time I see this!!

Comment: I think I may be mistaken, this is the first time im using the debugger, sorry. The debugger seems to execute the For line and stops with a yellow highlight on the next line. Im not sure if the error is in the for line or the next one.

Comment: OK, so when you click on Debug in the error window, it'll highlight the line where the error is. So if it is the `.Copy` line, check your sheets' names (I've added a line in my answer to display the name that the code is looking for, press Ctrl+G to display the immediate window! ;) )

Comment: Immediate window "Challan Details"

Comment: Ok and do you have a sheet with that name? Does it go into error on the next line?

Comment: Yes, I do have a sheet with that name, I tried to remove that particular sheet from the array but it gives the same error for the next sheet also. Instead of "Challan Details" i get "Deductee details" now.

Comment: Are those sheets in the workbook where the code is?

Comment: I was saving the Macro as a Personal.xlsb. After your suggestion I changed it to that worksheet and now it works. I wanted the code to export all the worksheets in the array to 1 new workbook, I wasnt clear enough in the question I think. I managed to get it done by removing the variablesheetarray line and inputting the sheet array directly in the Copy sheet function. Thank a lot for your help @R3uK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick, I have an issue with the Filters so I added a bit of error handling!

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
' Save as
''
Dim tB As Excel.Workbook
Dim wB As Excel.Workbook
Dim ExportArray As Variant
Dim ShName As Variant
Dim ExportName As String

Dim varResult As Variant

Set tB = ThisWorkbook
ExportArray = Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3")

For Each ShName In ExportArray
    Debug.Print ShName
    tB.Sheets(ShName).Copy
    Set wB = ActiveWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
        ExportName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(tB.Path & "\Textstring123", "Excel Files *.xls", , "Save " & ShName)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            ExportName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(tB.Path & "\Textstring123", , , "Save " & ShName)
        Else
            'No error, everything went well with filters
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'String 8 and Boolean 11
    If VarType(ExportName) <> 8 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        wB.SaveAs Filename:=ExportName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
    End If
    DoEvents
    wB.Close
Next ShName

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I am still understanding the code and learning. When I tried to execute the code I am getting runtime error 9: Subscript out of range. The line of code which is being highlighted is 

    tB.Sheets(ShName).Copy

In the Array() I have refered to the sheet using assigned name and not sheet name. That is the correct treatment right?

Comment: @UK97 : It seems right yeah, you should define the name of the sheet you want to export in `ExportArray = Array("...","...",...)`

Comment: Is it because shName variable has not been defined before that line? If yes, how do you define that Variable?